# Is it possible to transfer kafka users from one Zookeeper to another?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We are using SASL scram, the users and passwords are created and stored on our zookeeper instance. we can get the list of users with hashed passwords using

`kafka-configs --describe --zookeeper <zookeeperurl> --entity-type users`

I want to move these users and passwords onto a different instance of zookeeper. Is there a way I can transer them or even get the plain text passwords so that I can recreate them on the other instance?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted?

Comment: I'd suggest using a different centralized auth service like Kerberos + LDAP. Kafka itself does not provide tooling around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the users and passwords are created and stored on our zookeeper instance ?

maybe you could just connect zookeeper server with zookeeper client and get any data you want recursively?